# PHP Warning: Division by zero in */public_html/wp-content/themes/news/functions.php on line 20

Tags: php, division

Got this errors keeps appeared repeatedly

Here is my line 20 on functions.php

```
$wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']);
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this quotes?

Comment: I'm facing this problem too, but I found it only occurs when I use the demo named "adventure", so I simply changed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `found_posts` is 0, then it generates a warning of division by 0.

A quick fix would be to add `@` in front of `ceil` to supress warnings:

```
$wp_query->max_num_pages = @ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']);
```

Comment: this will return true or false, not a result.

Comment: the `@` sign doesn't affect the operation. it justs for supressing warnings

Answer (score 1):

```
if($wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] > 0)
    $wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']);
```

Try this it will skip your error.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "Division by zero", then `$wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']` must be 0 or a null/blank equivalent.

Comment: Thanks macuzzi. I try ur method and are able to get rid of the error

Answer (score 0):

```
$wp_query->max_num_pages = #ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']);
```

Have you tried adding a `#` before ceil as shown in the example above?